# Join a particular column in @JoinColumns

Tags: java, hibernate

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns
({
    @JoinColumn(name="ADDR_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"),
    @JoinColumn(name="ADDR_ZIP", referencedColumnName="ZIP")
})
public Address getAddress() { return address; }
```

How to join a particular column in `@JoinColumns`? For instance, if there is a composite PK in Address class containing ID and ZIP, how can I join only the "ID" column so that only a `ADDR_ID` column is created and not `ADDR_ZIP`?

`@MapsId("ID")` is not working to refer to only ID and exclude ZIP.

Is it possible in hibernate?

Comment: describe your problem in more detail, if ID is unique, why do you have a composite key in your db?

Comment: @KalpeshSoni :No ADDR_ID is not unique.But I require only tat particular column in my table and not ADDR_ZIP.Is it possible to join on only a particular column of a composite PK?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to join one column, you should try:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns
({
    @JoinColumn(name="ADDR_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
})
public Address getAnotherAddress() { return address; }
```

Comment: No u cant use a single column.JoinColumn of all the fields composing the primary key should be used.OT it will throw org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames referencing not mapped to a single property

Answer (score 0):

JPQL is where you define join criteria and get desired results back

entity definition maps java to your db world

if ID matches multiple Address, you get a List<> back